# How to set the background color on p-button using external css or tailwind css

Tags: html, css, angular-material, primeng

I'm designing a popup element with a p-button. I've tried background colour using styleClass="p-button-secondary", but it seems it's not like dark black. I also tried external css, but I could not set the background colour I expected.

My HTML Code :

```
<p-button styleClass="p-button-secondary prime-button-black" style="background: #161b2900;"
          class="ml-3 mb-4 mt-0 prime-button-black" (click)="st.toggle($event)">
          <mat-icon class="bg-white text-black rounded-full mr-4" [icIcon]="icAdd"></mat-icon>
          <span>Create System Type</span>
</p-button>
```

My external Css :

```
.p-button .prime-button-black {
  background-color:#161b2900  !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the css selector to `p-button` and provide a valid and visible color hex. You have provided eight value hex color i.e. `161b2900` where last two digits are alpha component, indicating its transparency. 0 represents a fully transparent color and `ff` is for complete opaque. In your case `00` is making the background color completely transparent.

```css
p-button{
  background-color: #161b2944 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <p-button styleClass="p-button-secondary prime-button-black" style="background: #161b2900;" class="ml-3 mb-4 mt-0 prime-button-black" (click)="st.toggle($event)">
    <mat-icon class="bg-white text-black rounded-full mr-4" [icIcon]="icAdd"></mat-icon>
    <span>Create System Type</span>
  </p-button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `#161b2900` is a valid hex-color. The last 2 digits are the alpha value. Besides that, using color instead of background-color is not an intended outcome.

Comment: @tacoshy yup, understood, but last two `00` would make the background-color completely transparent. I've added this explanation to my answer. Refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hex-color

Comment: @tacoshy I hope you have solved this issue.